# Form submitting even when it is returning false

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I can't seem to stop my form from submitting, even when it is shown that it is returning false. Could someone please help me spot out the error?

Here is my html code:

```
<form role="form" onsubmit="return login()" action="03_select_survey.html">

<!-- Username -->
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="user">Username:</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="user" placeholder="Enter Username">
</div>

<!-- Password -->
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
  <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter password">
</div>

<!-- Submit button -->
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Submit</button>
```

And here is my JavaScript code:

```
function login() {
  "use strict";

  // Variables
  var username,
    password,
    xmlhttp,
    isFound;

  // Get username and password
  username = document.getElementById("user");
  password = document.getElementById("pwd");

  // If username or password is empty
  if (username.value === "" || password.value === "") {
    window.alert("Incorrect username or password.");
    return false;
  } else {
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
      xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else { // code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp = new window.ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState === 4 && xmlhttp.status === 200) {
        isFound = xmlhttp.responseText;
        // Check if login info exists in database
        if (isFound.value === "true") {
          return true;
        } else {
          return false;
        }
      }
    };
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET", "login.php?user=" + username.value + "&pass=" +      password.value, true);
  xmlhttp.send();
  if (xmlhttp.onreadystatechange === true) {
      return true;
  } else {
      window.alert("Why won't you stop submitting?");
      return false;
  }
}
```

The code is reaching the "return false;" within the AJAX call, since it is alerting me with the message, but when I click OK, it proceeds to the next page instead of staying on the current page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Show us at least the  tag code as well. But the short answer it you're not stopping the form post. xmlHttp is asynchronus, so when you click your submit button, the command is fired off, but the function "login()" exits WITHOUT returning false. You need to return false from that function to stop the POST.

Here is a sample of what I would do....

```js
function login() {
  "use strict";

  // Variables
  var username,
    password,
    xmlhttp,
    isFound;

  // Get username and password
  username = document.getElementById("user");
  password = document.getElementById("pwd");

  // If username or password is empty
  if (username.value === "" || password.value === "") {
    window.alert("Incorrect username or password.");
    return false;
  } else {
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
      xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else { // code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp = new window.ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState === 4 && xmlhttp.status === 200) {
        alert('AJAX Response.....');
        isFound = xmlhttp.responseText;
        // Check if login info exists in database
        if (isFound.value === "true") {
          alert('We are good! Use JavaScript to navigate to new page...');
          window.location = '03_select_survey.html';
          return true;
        } else {
          alert('Not OK! They are not allowed in!');
          return false;
        }
      } else {
        alert('AJAX State Change we didn\'t expect.....');
        return false; // In case we need to stop the form POST
      }
    };
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET", "login.php?user=" + username.value + "&pass=" + password.value, true);
  xmlhttp.send();
  return false; // This false prevents FORM POST if we drop through before the async AJAX call finishes above
}
```

```html
<form role="form" onsubmit="return login();">
  <!-- The form doesn't need action="03_select_survey.html" -->

  <!-- Username -->
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="user">Username:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="user" placeholder="Enter Username">
  </div>

  <!-- Password -->
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter password">
  </div>

  <!-- Submit button -->
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: I try adding the "Check if login info exists in database" part after the open and send request, but somehow that doesn't even make the alert pops up. I'm new to stackoverflow, as well as to html and js, so I'm not sure of how everything work.

Comment: Is the problem that it's still posting the form and goinf to the next page, or that an alert is not showing up? You mentioned the problem is the form is posting and going to the next page.

Comment: Yes, and since the "return false" is in the same block of code as the alert statement, I use it as a check to see what is going on. In the code that I posted, the alert "Why won't you stop submitting?" is popping up, but then the form still gets submitted. After taking out the if/else statement inside the onreadystatechange function() and adding it to the bottom of the login() function, after the open and send requests, the alert doesn't even pop up at all, and the form is still being submitted.

Comment: The code in your function doesn't execute LINEARLY. The xmlHttp call is ASYNCHRONOUS. That means your code gets to the login function, executes the code getting/checking the username/password, sets up the xmlHttp object, then executes the LAST LINE -- xmlHttp.send() and EXITS the function WITHOUT returning false, so your page posts. The callback xmlHttp.onreadystatechange is called AFTER you leave that function as it is a CALLBACK and closure keeps it around after the function call. Try putting "return false'" after xmlHttp.send().

Comment: Okay, I see what you mean. I think I got it working. This is what I found out:
The isFound variable value is correct, but when the function () exits, the value in isFound is not retained (might be an obvious thing but I'm kinda new to this so I didn't know). So what I did is that I had the if/else check inside the function () and have it either return true or false, then have another if/else statement after xmlhttp.send(), checking the value of xmlhttp.onreadystatechange, and returning true or false based on that. And that seems to do the trick.

Comment: Sorry nvm, it's still not working correctly. I had it print out the value of isFound, and then print out either true or false depending on the value of xmlhttp.onreadystatechange, and it's always printing out false for the latter. I'm not sure how I can do a check to tell the page to either return true or false OUTSIDE of the function ().

Comment: Update your code samples above and include the <form> tag as part of the code this time.

Comment: Okay done. So basically I'm trying to get login() to either return true or false, but I'm not sure which variable to use to make the decision.

Comment: I edited my answer above with what I would do. I tested this and it works (with different page names, of course).

Comment: Oh wow, I did not know that you could do it like that. So the attribute action made the form to always be submitted? I thought it would only perform the action if the function returns true?